# MySQL and using SELECT from custom position

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL problem that I can't figure out.

I run a query:

```
SELECT id, totalsum FROM table ORDER BY totalsum DESC
```

This could give me the following result:

```
1, 10000
4, 90000
8, 80000
3, 50000
5, 40000
++++
```

What is need is a code that should work something like this:

```
SELECT id, totalsum 
FROM table ORDER BY totalsum DESC
START LISTING FROM id=8 AND CONTINUE TO THE END OF RESULT / LIMIT
```

Resulting in someting like this

```
8, 80000
3, 50000
5, 40000
++++
```

I can not use this query:

```
SELECT id, totalsum 
FROM table 
WHERE id>=8
ORDER BY totalsum DESC
```

Because the id could be both < and >.

Have tried using LIMIT AND OFFSET but that resulting in very slow speed.

Any advice pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated!

Comment: `WHERE totalsum >= (SELECT totalsum FROM table WHERE id = 8)` should do the trick, right?

Comment: Your first query has `ORDER BY totalsum DESC`, but the results are not actually sorted by `totalsum`. This makes the rest of the question a bit unclear. Please fix your datasets so it properly fits to your question.

Comment: *I can not use this query [...] Because the id could be both < and >*. It looks this query would give you the rows that you want, though (ie: rows whose `id` equal to or greater than 8). Why is that not a viable solution for you?

Comment: So `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Then stare at the datatype for `totalsum`.

Comment: Without an index on `totalsum`, there is no way to optimize `LIMIT` and/or `OFFSET`.

Comment: I'll bet that was 100000, not 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

1. Assign each row a row_num based on totalsum in descending order (CTE)
2. Select from the above where row_num >= the row_num of id=8

```
create table a_table (
    id      int,
    total   int);
    
insert into a_table values
(1, 100000),
(4, 90000),
(8, 80000),
(3, 50000),
(5, 40000);


with cte as (
select id,
       total,
       row_number() over (order by total desc) as row_num
  from a_table)
select *
  from cte
 where row_num >= (select row_num from cte where id=8);
```

Result:

```
id|total|row_num|
--+-----+-------+
 8|80000|      3|
 3|50000|      4|
 5|40000|      5|
```

EDIT:
The above query may return wrong result if other rows have the same total. A comment said it well, just use the following query can do the job:

```
select id, total
  from a_table
 where total <= (select total from a_table where id=8)
 order by total desc;
```